# How to predict in kknn function? library(kknn)

Tags: r, knn, nearest-neighbor

I try to use `kknn` + loop to create a leave-out-one cross validation for a model, and compare that with train.kknn.

I have split the data into two parts: training (80% data), and test (20% data). In the training data, I exclude one point in the loop to manually create LOOCV.

I think something gets wrong in `predict(knn.fit, data.test)`. I have tried to find how to predict in `kknn` through the kknn package instruction and online but all the examples are "summary(model)" and "table(validation...)" rather than the prediction on a separate test data. The code `predict(model, dataset)` works successfully in `train.kknn` function, so I thought I could use the similar arguments in kknn.

I am not sure if there is such a prediction function in `kknn`. If yes, what arguments should I give?

Look forward to your suggestion. Thank you.

```r
library(kknn)
for (i in 1:nrow(data.train)) {
    train.data <- data.train[-i,]
    validation.data <- data.train[i,]
    knn.fit <- kknn(as.factor(R1)~., train.data, validation.data, k = 40,
                    kernel = "rectangular", scale = TRUE)
    # train.data + validation.data is the 80% data I split.
}

pred.knn <- predict(knn.fit, data.test) # data.test is 20% data.
```

Here is the error message:

> Error in switch(type, raw = object$fit, prob = object$prob,
>   stop("invalid type for prediction")) :    EXPR must be a length 1
>   vector

Actually I try to compare train.kknn and kknn+loop to compare the results of the leave-out-one CV. I have two more questions:

1) in `kknn`: is it possible to use another set of data as test data to see the knn.fit prediction?

2) in `train.kknn`: I split the data and use 80% of the whole data  and intend to use the rest 20% for prediction. Is it an correct common practice?

2) Or should I just use the original data (the whole data set) for `train.kknn`, and create a loop: `data[-i,]` for training, `data[i,]` for validation in `kknn`? So they will be the counterparts?

I find that if I use the training data in the `train.kknn` function and use prediction on test data set, the best k and kernel are selected and directly used in generating the predicted value based on the test dataset.

In contrast, if I use `kknn` function and build a loop of different k values, the model generates the corresponding prediction results based on
the test data set each time the k value is changed. Finally, in `kknn` + loop, the best k is selected based on the best actual prediction accuracy rate of test data. In short, the best k `train.kknn` selected may not work best on test data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For objects returned by `kknn`, `predict` gives the predicted value or the predicted probabilities of `R1` for the single row contained in `validation.data`:

```
predict(knn.fit)
predict(knn.fit, type="prob")
```

The `predict` command also works on objects returned by `train.knn`.
For example:

```
train.kknn.fit <- train.kknn(as.factor(R1)~., data.train, ks = 10,
                      kernel = "rectangular", scale = TRUE)
class(train.kknn.fit)
# [1] "train.kknn" "kknn"

pred.train.kknn <- predict(train.kknn.fit, data.test)
table(pred.train.kknn, as.factor(data.test$R1))
```

The `train.kknn` command implements a leave-one-out method very close to the loop developed by @vcai01. See the following example:

```
set.seed(43210)
n <- 500
data.train <- data.frame(R1=rbinom(n,1,0.5), matrix(rnorm(n*10), ncol=10))

library(kknn)
pred.kknn <- array(0, nrow(data.train))
for (i in 1:nrow(data.train)) {
    train.data <- data.train[-i,]
    validation.data <- data.train[i,]
    knn.fit <- kknn(as.factor(R1)~., train.data, validation.data, k = 40,
                    kernel = "rectangular", scale = TRUE)
    pred.kknn[i] <- predict(knn.fit)
}

knn.fit <- train.kknn(as.factor(R1)~., data.train, ks = 40,
                      kernel = "rectangular", scale = TRUE)
pred.train.kknn <- predict(knn.fit, data.train)
table(pred.train.kknn, pred.kknn)

#                pred.kknn
# pred.train.kknn   1   2
#               0 374  14
#               1   9 103
```

Comment: Thank you, Marco. In the solution of kknn you suggested, the predicted value/probablity is based on validation.data. I have two more questions: 1) Is it possible to use another set of data as test data to see the knn.fit prediction? Actually I try to compare train.kknn and kknn+loop to compare the results of the leave-out-one CV.  I split the data and use 80% of the whole data in train.kknn; 2) Or should I just use the original data (the whole data set) for train.kknn, but split 80% data for training, 20% for validation in kknn? So they will be the counterparts?

Comment: @vcai01 `train.kknn` use the leave-one-out method. Hence, it is an algorithm very close to your kknn+loop. You should get similar prediction from the two methods. I edited my answer adding an illustrative example. I hope it can help you. Upvote and accept the answer if you find it useful. Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, Marco! It helps me better understand the difference between the train.kknn, and kknn.